# How to add key and value to JSON if key not exists in SQL

Tags: sql, json

I have ouptput json as

```
DECLARE @ouptputJson nvarchar(max)='[
  {
    "Name": "BSData",
    "Value": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "ISData",
    "Value": "{\"WC\":{\"IL\":\"false\",\"SCB\":\"false\"},\"RC\":[{\"PrimaryKeys\":\"\",\"BackupMode\":\"NONE\"}],\"SIData\":{\"builderId\":\"4567\",\"column\":{\"EP_Key\":\"5678\"}}}"
  }
]'
```

In @ouptputJson, I need to search for key "Battery" under "column" object and If Battery key is not found in @ouptputJson, then I need to add (key,value) Which should look like below

```
  {
    "Name": "BSData",
    "Value": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "ISData",
    "Value": "{\"WC\":{\"IL\":\"false\",\"SCB\":\"false\"},\"RC\":[{\"PrimaryKeys\":\"\",\"BackupMode\":\"NONE\"}],\"SIData\":{\"builderId\":\"4567\",\"column\":{\"Battery\":\"Epr Oxygen\",\"EP_Key\":\"5678\"}}}"
  }
]'
```

I have tried in this way,

```
Declare @ouptputJson nvarchar(max)='[
  {
    "Name": "BSData",
    "Value": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "ISData",
    "Value": "{\"WC\":{\"IL\":\"false\",\"SCB\":\"false\"},\"RC\":[{\"PrimaryKeys\":\"\",\"BackupMode\":\"NONE\"}],\"SIData\":{\"builderId\":\"4567\",\"column\":{\"EP_Key\":\"5678\"}}}"
  }
]'



SELECT
          j1.Name,
          Value = CASE WHEN j1.Name = 'ISData'
               THEN JSON_MODIFY(j1.value, 'append $.Battery', 'Epr Oxygen')
               ELSE j1.Value
               END
        FROM OPENJSON (@ouptputJson)
          WITH (
            Name nvarchar(100),
            Value nvarchar(max)
          ) j1
        FOR JSON PATH;
```

but it is adding key Battery outside of column object

```
[{"Name":"BSData","Value":""},{"Name":"ISData","Value":"{\"WC\":{\"IL\":\"false\",\"SCB\":\"false\"},\"RC\":[{\"PrimaryKeys\":\"\",\"BackupMode\":\"NONE\"}],\"SIData\":{\"builderId\":\"4567\",\"column\":{\"EP_Key\":\"5678\"}},\"Battery\":[\"Epr Oxygen\"]}"}]
```

Comment: Please provide information on which SGDB you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The *append* argument is used to append new value to the array referenced by , this is way the added value appears as an array at the highest level.

No need to use *append*, just edit The *json path* to `$.SIData.column.Battery` :

```
SELECT j1.Name,
       Value = CASE WHEN j1.Name = 'ISData'
               THEN JSON_MODIFY(j1.value, '$.SIData.column.Battery', 'Epr Oxygen')
               ELSE j1.Value
               END
FROM OPENJSON (@ouptputJson)
     WITH (
            Name nvarchar(100),
            Value nvarchar(max)
     ) j1
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TXtWENNb)